# Is it possible to assign/change custom icons for files in a batch / from commandline?

Tags: nautilus-script

Actually, I'm talking about icons for **Nautilus Scripts**, and I have many of them. Although I prefer menus without icons, I cannot prevent icons from being displayed in Nautilus context menu items **Open With** and **Scripts**.

Particularly, having the same script icon displayed for all of them does not look good at all.
So, if I cannot prevent them, at least I'd like them use icons better related with the function of each script.

It's easy to assign a custom icon for a single file through **File Properties** but I have a total of **82 Nautilus Scripts** at the moment!

When you enter `gvfs-info /path/to/file` command in terminal, you can see a line like this: `metadata::custom-icon: file:///usr/share/icons/NITRUX-Buttons/apps/scalable/accessories-text-editor.svg`

I wonder if it is possible at all to edit this line (where ever it is) in a batch / from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't see it in the list shown as I was writing this question, but later I saw a similar question and the answer I was looking for in the list of Related questions on the right:

[**How can I programmatically change a file's icon?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217757/how-can-i-programmatically-change-a-files-icon?rq=1)

It seems basically the command for this is:

`gvfs-set-attribute -t string /path/to/your/file metadata::custom-icon file:///path/to/your/icon.png`

***Notes:***

*1. This doesn't seem to work for Nautilus Scripts in Ubuntu versions before 12.10.*

*2. This doesn't seem to work for Nautilus Scripts when running Nautilus as root either.*

Answer (score 0):

Using the ideas exposed here, changing the icon from Nautilus or Nemo would take this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Written by Alfonso R. Reyes
# make hard links for multiple file selection
# be careful of not moving the hard link to a different file system
HARDLINK_ICON=${HOME}/.local/share/icons/mine/folder-green-activities-icon.png
for arg 
do
    # make a hard link of the selected file
    if [[ -f "$arg" ]] 
    then
        HARDLINK_NAME="Hard Link to $arg"
        ln "$arg" "${HARDLINK_NAME}"
        gio set -t string "${HARDLINK_NAME}" metadata::custom-icon file:///${HARDLINK_ICON}
    fi
done
```