# Is it possible to backup all my Nautilus personalized icons?

Tags: scripts, nautilus, icons, backup, productivity

I like to personalize my `Nautilus` icons from folders and files with images.

[image]

The problem is that all the times that I format my computer I lose all the icons that I've worked so hard to organize. So, is there a way to backup all these personalized "thumbnails" that I've been using on `Nautilus`? Where are they stored? Can I backup the configuration from a specific folder and then replicate it on a different computer that uses `Nautilus` and has the same folder structure?

Comment: Please mention your OS version, desktop environment, and version of Nautilus. Nautilus has had features added/removed rather frequently.

Comment: @DKBose I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity and the version of Nautilus is 3.14.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically change a file's icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217757/how-can-i-programmatically-change-a-files-icon)

Comment: @db429: While that *does* explain quite a few things about the topic in question a way to back-up custom file icons is not among them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up creating a script to solve my problem. That's not exactly a backup solution but it works for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

folderToBeUpdated="$HOME/folderToInsertIconsRecursively"
iconsFolder="$HOME/.icons"

file="$(mktemp)"

# Generate a recursive list of all folders and files inside the folder $folderToBeUpdated
ls -R "$folderToBeUpdated" | awk '
/:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
/:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}
NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }' > $file

# Start inserting icons dynamically on files and folders
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   folderName="$(basename "${line}")"
   pathName="$(dirname "${line}")"
   if [ -f "$iconsFolder"/"$folderName".png ]   
   then
   gvfs-set-attribute -t string "$pathName/$folderName" metadata::custom-icon "file://$iconsFolder/$folderName.png"
   fi  
done < $file
```

The idea of this script is that we need to give it the path of two folders:

1. The path of a folder full of icons (`iconsFolder`)
2. The path of the folder we wish to put icons recursively  (`folderToBeUpdated`)

The script will **check** the icons and the folders with the **same name** and then it will **insert icons on specific folders in case that's true**, e.g a folder inside `folderToBeUpdated` is called `example` and I have an icon called `example.png` inside my `iconsFolder`, so the icon `example.png` will be inserted as the folder `example`'s icon (if the name isn't the same the script won't do anything).

PS: It's necessary to press `F5` after running the script in order to see the icons.

---

That's just a functional script but it turns out to be useful because I can easily replicate my icons on different computers. In any case, if anyone knows a way to do backups of icons in a more convenient way, feel free to write a new answer or give suggestions in the comments.