# How do I change the icon of a specific file [not file type!]?

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, files, icons

Running Xubuntu 18.04.

Is there a way to change the file icon of a specific file, not all files of that type?
For example, I have a file with no extension - it makes it look like a .txt file. How can I change that to - let's say - a python script? Is it possible? It is possible on Windows, so why not Ubuntu?

Comment: I think this is a Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217757/how-can-i-programmatically-change-a-files-icon

Comment: The tool is deprecated, and gio set does not work?

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread ( https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365446 ) you can't change the file icon for a single file directly if using XFCE. You could create a .desktop file and use the `exec` command to launch the script. Example of .Desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=AppName
Comment=Some Comment
Exec=python somescript.py
Icon=false_icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Script
```