# How to change preview image for file from command line?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, thumbnails

If I open the properties window for some random file. If I click on the file icon in that window I can select a new preview image (thumbnail) for the file. This preview will be displayed in the file browser. How can do this from the command line?

(Because going through the gui to change file preview image takes a lot of time and clicking, I want to write a shell function or just an alias so that I can quickly change the preview of a couple of files in a directory)

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp3c6fmugxbfr4y/fileproperties_edited.png?dl=0]

Comment: I would have loved to give you the answer, but it's already here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217757/how-can-i-programmatically-change-a-files-icon

Comment: To read the current metadata: http://askubuntu.com/a/153586/72216 more info: `man gvfs`

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes, my bad, its *exactly* the same.))

Comment: I can imagine you assumed it wasn't asked before. I liked the question!