# Where does Ubuntu put my icon settings?

Tags: nautilus, icons

When I change the icons of my folders, where does Ubuntu store these icon settings? I would like to know because I set the wrong picture to be the icon of folder, so I replaced it with another picture which was as the same filename as the wrong one, but the icon didn't change. How can I change the icon?

Comment: Good question and while it's not an exact duplicate, you may find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153586/12864) helpful. It's `gvfs` storing the metadata, not Nautilus itself. Because of the renaming, it's probably Nautilus caching a copy of the old icon causing your issue. Try [restarting Nautilus](http://askubuntu.com/a/19981/12864) to see if that refreshes the icon.

Comment: @TomBrossman Could you make it as an answer?

Comment: It's probably best if you copy whatever worked from my comment (or the linked answers) and post an answer to your own question, which is encouraged here. I don't know what worked for you so I would just be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The iconpacks are stored in /usr/share/icons/ . Many icon packs are stored in this folder. To change the icon for a particular app or folder replace the file with the same name in the icon pack you are using. By default , ubuntu uses unity-mono-dark iconthemes stored at location /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark. To change the icon theme, I use [unity tweak tool.](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/)